# Hacer backup de todas las tablas, triggers y procedimientos almacenados que tenga en MySQL con codigo php

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo hecha una función para hacer una backup, al pulsar un botón, de
todas las tablas y sus contenidos a una copia de seguridad. Me
funciona perfectamente. Pero me interesa además poder hacer backups
también de todos los procedimientos almacenados que tengo en la mysql
así como de todos los triggers creados. He probado varias maneras
pero nada.

Mirando en la ayuda de las FAQs de MySQL he encontrado esta solución
pero no me funciona:

```
mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases > archivo_respaldo.sql
```

Hago lo siguiente:

```
<?php $dump_string = "mysqldump -u root -p
   --all-databases > archivo_respaldo.sql"; exec($dump_string); ?>
```

Pero nada, me crea el fichero archivo_respaldo.sql pero está totalmente
vacío, no mete nada dentro de él.

¿Alguien conoce algún otro método para hacer de golpe, mediante
programanción PHP, un backup de todas las tablas, triggers y
procedimientos almacenados que tenga mi bd MySQL? esta funcion solo me genera los query de las tablas y no de los triggers y procedimientos almacenados

```
function RespaldarBase($strHost,$strUsuario,$strPassword,$strBaseDeDatos, $tablas=false, $strNombreRespaldo=false){ 
//Limite de tiempo 
set_time_limit(3000);
//CONEXION CON MySQL
$mysqli = new mysqli($strHost,$strUsuario,$strPassword,$strBaseDeDatos); 
//SELECCIONAMOS LA BASE DATOS 
$mysqli->select_db($strBaseDeDatos); 
//ASIGNAMOS LA INTERCALACIÓN
$mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
//SELECCIONAMOS LAS TABLAS DE TODA LA BASE DE DATOS
$queryTablas = $mysqli->query('SHOW TABLES'); 
//GUARDAMOS LAS TABLAS EN UN ARREGLO
while($row = $queryTablas->fetch_row()) { 
    $arrTablas[] = $row[0]; 
}
//SOLO LAS TABLAS QUE ESCOJAMOS O TODAS SI LE ASIGNAMOS EL VALOR DE FALSO
if($tablas !== false) { 
    $arrTablas = array_intersect( $arrTablas, $tablas); 
} 
    //ENCABEZADO DEL RESPALDO
$Contenido = "SET SQL_MODE = \"NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO\";\r\nSET time_zone = \"+00:00\";\r\n\r\n\r\n/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;\r\n/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;\r\n/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;\r\n/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;\r\n--\r\n-- Database: `".$name."`\r\n--\r\n\r\n\r\n";
//HACEMOS EL BARRIDO DE LAS TABLAS PARA GENERAR EL RESPALDO
```

foreach($arrTablas as $tabla){
if (empty($tabla)){ continue; }
$resultado  = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM `'.$tabla.'`');
$totalCampos=$resultado->field_count;
$NumeroRenglones=$mysqli->affected_rows;
$res = $mysqli->query('SHOW CREATE TABLE '.$tabla);
$TableMLine=$res->fetch_row();
$Contenido .= "\n\n".$TableMLine[1].";\n\n";
$TableMLine[1]=str_ireplace('CREATE TABLE `','CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` ',$TableMLine[1]);
for ($i = 0, $contador = 0; $i < $totalCampos;   $i++, $contador=0) {
while($row = $resultado->fetch_row()){
//when started (and every after 100 command cycle):
if ($contador%100 == 0 || $contador == 0 )  {
$Contenido .= "\nINSERT INTO ".$tabla." VALUES";
}
$Contenido .= "\n(";
for($j=0; $j<$totalCampos; $j++){
$row[$j] = str_replace("\n","\n", addslashes($row[$j]) );
if (isset($row[$j])){
$Contenido .= '"'.$row[$j].'"';
}  else{$Contenido .= '""';
}
if ($j<($totalCampos-1)){
$Contenido.= ',';
}
}
$Contenido .=")";
//every after 100 command cycle [or at last line] ....p.s. but should be inserted 1 cycle eariler
if ( (($contador+1)%100==0 && $contador!=0) || $contador+1==$NumeroRenglones) {
$Contenido .= ";";
}
else {
$Contenido .= ",";
}   $contador=$contador+1;
}
} $Contenido .="\n\n\n";
}
$Contenido .= "\r\n\r\n/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;\r\n/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;\r\n/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;";
$strNombreRespaldo = $strNombreRespaldo.'__*('.date('H-i-s').'*'.date('d-m-Y').').sql';
ob_get_clean();
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
header('Content-Length: '. (function_exists('mb_strlen') ? mb_strlen($Contenido, '8bit'): strlen($Contenido)) );
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename="".$strNombreRespaldo.""");
//  echo $Contenido;
//exit;

```
file_put_contents($strNombreRespaldo, $Contenido);
    //COMPRIME EL ARCHIVO
    $zip = new ZipArchive(); //Objeto de Libreria ZipArchive
$salida_zip = $strBaseDeDatos.'.zip';
if($zip->open($strNombreRespaldo.".zip",ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)===true) { //Creamos y abrimos el archivo ZIP
    $zip->addFile($strNombreRespaldo); //Agregamos el archivo SQL a ZIP
    $zip->close(); //Cerramos el ZIP
} else {
    echo 'Error'; //Enviamos el mensaje de error
}
```

}
RespaldarBase("localhost","desarrol_gtousa","GTOUSA2020$","desarrol_gtousa2",false, "mirespaldo");

y la mando a llamar de esta forma

```
RespaldarBase("localhost","root","mypassword","mybasededatos",false, "mirespaldo");
```

Alguien tendrá un script que realice tal operación?  se los agradeceré

Answer (score 2):

Si desea realizar una copia de seguridad completa, es decir, todas las bases de datos, procedimientos, rutinas y eventos sin interrumpir ninguna conexión:

```
mysqldump -u [username] -p -A -R -E --triggers --single-transaction > respaldo_completo.sql
```

**-A** Para todas las bases de datos (también puede usar --all-databases)

**-R** Para todas las rutinas (procedimientos almacenados y triggers)

**-E** Para todos los eventos

**--single-transaction** Sin bloquear las tablas, es decir, sin interrumpir ninguna conexión.

Comment: Realice eso pero me genera un archivo Sql vacio.  prove barias opciones y pero el problema perciste, lo que estoy tratado de hacer ahora es mediante una funcion de PHP realizar un backup completo de la base de datos incluyendo  triggers, procedimientos, almacenados y funciones pero el escript que tengo solo me genera los query de las tablas y no las query de los triggers, procedimientos, almacenados y funciones.

Comment: Probaste la consulta desde la consola de mysql? Para validar que no sea tema de la consulta.

Comment: probe desde cmd con otro usuario y me genero el backup pero me creo esto antes de los insert into 

--
-- Dumping data for table `com_det_requisicion`
--

LOCK TABLES `com_det_requisicion` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `com_det_requisicion` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `com_det_requisicion` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `com_det_requisicion` VALUES (1,15,'Inventory Part','CAFE INCASA AZUL12 - 5.29 oz / 150 gr',10,0,75,25,0.33,2.50,62.50);

Comment: Cuál es el problema de esas líneas? A grandes rasgos es una indicación para compartir el uso de la tabla, en este caso `com_det_requisicion` y lo siguiente es un comentario. Prueba con el mismo usuario con el que te conectas en el código PHP y listo.